# How can I open multiple windows in one application, and show them at the same time?

Tags: unity

Example scenario: Let's say I'm on my desktop and I do the following:

1. open a full-screen window in application A
2. open two half-screen windows (tiled to the left and right) in application B
3. go back to the desktop (with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>)
4. show the first window (application A).
5. move the mouse over the icon of application B
6. scroll the scroll wheel

   - When I do this, I get the first window that was tiled to the right, and I see application A in the background. So far, everything is good.
7. scroll the scroll wheel again (to try to see the second window of application A)

   - Here's when the problem occurs. When I try doing this, the first window from application B disappears, and the second window shows. I still see application A in the background where the first window of application B used to be.
   - 7a. (expected result) both windows of application B are visible, and application A is covered up in the background

Here's a small diagram:

```
6. BBBBAAAA 7. AAAABBBB 7a. B1B1B2B2 (expected)
   BBBBAAAA    AAAABBBB     B1B1B2B2
   BBBBAAAA    AAAABBBB     B1B1B2B2
```

How can I achieve this expected result? Right now I'm sticking the mouse to the left edge of the screen and clicking the icon to get the "open windows" dialog thingy and opening both manually, but there must be a quicker and more efficient way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like the shortcut <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> (a backtick). Similar to alt tab, <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> switches between windows of the same application.

So if app B1 is in focus on the right, and you press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> app B2 will appear  with focus on the left.

Note that the apps will have the same geometry they had the last time they were in focus, so if you put app B1 on the right and app B2 on the right, app B2 will appear over app B1. This is rather obvious, but I'm saying it anyway.